# Z Index wont apply, position is already relative/absolute

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-position

I have a tool tip, and its basically not working. I did some searching, and the usual response is that you haven't added your position's, however I have those and im truly stumped.

The problem is that in the live demo below, the tool tip from the icons on the left, wont go on top of the content to the right, so I cant see it.

The code mainly lies here;

```
a.icon {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    
    }

a.icon .tooltip {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.2s, left 0.5s ease 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5 ease 0.2s, left 0.5s ease 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5 ease 0.2s, left 0.5s ease 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.5 ease 0.2s, left 0.5s ease 0.2s;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background:url('../images/tooltip.png') no-repeat bottom center;
    position:absolute;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:10px;
    width: 110px;
    display: block;
    top: 24px;
    z-index: 1000;
    }

a.icon:hover .tooltip {
    opacity: 1.0;
top:24px;
    
    }
```

And here is the HTML, with lorem removed;

```
<div id="icons">
<a href="info page" class="icon" id="info"><span class="tooltip">About Me</span>
<a href="portfolio page" class="icon" id="portfolio"><span                                            class="tooltip">Portfolio</span></a>
<a href="mailto:" class="icon" id="email"><span    class="tooltip">Mail</span></a>
<a href="?userinfo" class="icon" id="skype"><span     class="tooltip">Skype</span> </a>
<a href="" class="icon" id="twitter"><span class="tooltip">Twitter</span></a><!-- Holds the icons for the site -->
</div>
<div id="content">
raesent at quam velit,
</div>
```

There are span classes referring to tooltip, but this text box wont let me add them as code.

And in short, it doesn't work. I do have the example live here:

Sorry if its a pain to look through the code, im new to this, just starting my first portfolio, and I haven't organized or commented much yet.

Thanks very much.

Comment: IS the tooltip a child of another element? Can you post the relevant HTML too?

Comment: This is problem of opacity. I don't think you can fix it. Try to get rid off of opacity and it will work.

Comment: Hi think I have added the HTMl you need.

Comment: I have tried remaking the tooltip a thousand times, opacity wont go away. Unless i have code i cant see.

Answer (score 0):

.......................................

Hi now define your `#content` **position** and `z-index`

as like this

```
#content{
position:relative;
z-index:-1;
}
```

### **or** 2nd option

```
#icons{
position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

---

**for opacity**

**write this css**

```
#info:hover, #portfolio:hover, #email:hover, #skype:hover, #twitter:hover{
opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: I THINK that did it, however I seem to have some transparency knocking around somewhere making it difficult to see, ive been through the code and I cant tell anymore!

Comment: now do the opacity normal #info:hover,#portfolio:hover, #email:hover{opacity:1;} do the all id same like this